# Pandas Series: split, modify first, join

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Pandas Series with the names of cities and districts:

```
London:Alpha
London
London:Beta
London:Delta
Paris
```

I want to add "_sub" at the end of each city (but not districts!) name so that the converted series looks like this:

```
London_sub:Alpha
London_sub
London_sub:Beta
London_sub:Delta
Paris_sub
```

As far as I understand, I need to split, change 1st part and rejoin the series, so I tried this chain:

```
names_df[0] = names_df[0] \
        .str.split(':') \
        .apply(lambda x: x[0] + '_sub') \
        .str.join(':')
```

But in this way I've lost a district part (Alpha, Beta, Delta) and th result looks ugly:

```
L:o:n:d:o:n:_:s:u:b
```

I've tried another way:

```
names_df[0] = names_df[0]\
    .str.split(':')\
    .apply(lambda x: '_sub:'.join(x))
```

But it doesn't append '_sub' to rows withoud districts :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single regex substitution instead:

```
s = pd.Series(['London:Alpha', 'London', 'London:Beta', 'London:Delta', 'Paris'])
s = s.str.replace(r'^([^:]+)', r'\1_sub', regex=True)
```

- `^([^:]+)` - starting from the start of the string `^` captures a set of chars excepting `:` char

---

```
0    London_sub:Alpha
1          London_sub
2     London_sub:Beta
3    London_sub:Delta
4           Paris_sub
dtype: object
```